# Detecting if a text is selected in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, textselection

I need to check if any text selected in Autohotkey.
I have this function which works fine:

```
IsTextSelected()
{
    SavedClip := ClipboardAll()
    A_Clipboard := ""
    Send("^c")
    Errorlevel := !ClipWait(0.5) ; Wait for the clipboard to contain data
    if (!ErrorLevel) ; There is data on clipboard
        return (true)
    else
        return (false)
    ; Sleep(100)
    A_Clipboard := SavedClip
    SavedClip := ""
    return
}
```

But its too slow!
Is there a way to speed up the process?
Or is there another method to achieve that goal?

Comment: I wouldn't count on being able to get any actual solution for this. It's more likely you'd able to streamline your process in some other way. What's your end goal and use case here?

Comment: `ClipWait(0.5)` waits half a second. Does `ClipWait(0.1)` work?

Comment: @0x464e Here is a use case: I have a script to search selected text on google. If nothing selected, it calls another function to select the word under the cursor. Prior to this, I need to check if anything selected by calling IsTextSelected(). But this process has a noticeable lag which caused by this function.

Comment: @Hovercouch No, reducing the timeout does not make any difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct answer based on [Descolada](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=82&t=125304&p=557078#p557078) script. (requires [UIA.ahk](https://github.com/Descolada/UIA-v2/tree/main/Lib) in the same folder as the script)

```
#Include UIA.ahk
IsTextSelected()
{
    try if (el := UIA.GetFocusedElement()) && el.IsTextPatternAvailable {
        selectionRange := el.GetSelection()[2]
        If selectionRange.GetText()
            return true
        else
            return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if any faster for your need, but perhaps...

```
F1::
    RetainedClip := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard = 
        Send, ^c
    If Clipboard = 
        MsgBox, , , No text selected., 3
    Else
        MsgBox, , , Text is selected., 3
        Clipboard := RetainedClip
Return
```

Comment: This is the same solution that I mentioned in the first post. Except without preserving clipboard.